# Secure Shell isn't propery loading .bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, environment-variables, bashrc

I've got a seemingly simple issue - I have a 15.04 server that I connect to via `ssh`. Currently, I have a couple of folders added to my `PATH` environment variable in my `.bashrc` file:

```
#... (rest of .bashrc)

export PATH=$PATH:/home/athan/bin
```

This allows the `foo` command to be visible. When I secure-shell *directly* into the server, I can use `foo` just fine:

```
athan@mine $> ssh athan@place.com
athan@place $> foo
foo!
```

However, when I try and execute a command *remotely*, `foo` is nowhere to be found:

```
athan@mine $> ssh athan@place.com "foo"
bash: foo: command not found
```

Even stranger, when I explicitly `source` my `.bashrc`, it **still** can't be found:

```
athan@mine $> ssh athan@place.com 'bash -lc "source /home/athan/.bashrc && foo"'
bash: foo: command not found
```

Does the `sshd` remote procedure call have a different environment behavior? Is there a separate file I should be looking at? I have no idea what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, `.bashrc` is only sourced for interactive shells, but many linux distributions decide to build bash with a special option to also source it for non-interactive shells if a SSH_something variable is in the environment. However, it doesn't switch the shell to interactive mode when doing this, so the following `case` command near the top of the default `.bashrc`:

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Finds that the shell is not interactive, so it returns.

If you put the `PATH` assignment above that block, it should work. Just make sure whatever you put above that block does not output anything, as that will break `scp` and `rsync`.